# What headers are needed to be set while uploading PDF to S3, so it is not downloaded but viewed or rendered in browser?

Tags: javascript, pdf, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I know there are many similar questions, where adding `ContentDisposition = 'inline'` solves the issue of pdf being downloaded by default.

Below is the headers that I am passing while uploading the pdf.

```js
          Bucket: `${cookieJS.Bucket}${item.url !== '' ? `/${item.url}` : ''}`,
          Key: decodeURIComponent(`${this.kebabCaseName(item.name)}`),
          Body: item.entry,
          ACL: cookieJS.ACL,
          ContentType: item.entry.type, // application/pdf
          ContentDisposition: 'inline',
```

But in my case I have made such change & downloading is now not happening by default, but when I am accessing the pdf link, I am getting the Failed to load the document error in Chrome, and then upon reload the pdf is being loaded just fine.

I want to know why is there a error on first time? & I want to access the pdf in a application where reload is not possible.

This is the error -> [The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPtWl.png)

Comment: What is the error you get on the first download?

Comment: @cementblocks I have added the link to the error screenshot.

Comment: If you can give the actual error from the developer tools network request that would great.

Comment: @cementblocks I will add that when I go to office in few hours.

Comment: @cementblocks I checked in network tab of developer console. Their is nothing (it is empty) when first error occurs. After the refresh, their two request one for favicon & other for pdf itself.

Comment: Maybe you have an error in the javascript somewhere?

Comment: @cementblocks like what? Because this code is working just fine for all the other media types like images, videos and audios.